# Excel-Custom-Functions,Contoso.ADD42 function is not appearing in Excel

Tags: api, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I followed steps added here [Excel-Custom-Functions](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions). Hosted Customfunctions.html and customfunctions.js in IIS web app with self created SSL certificate.

- I hosted only above mentioned files.
- I created a folder in C drive, copied manifest with updated URL
  shared folder and copy network path.
- I added network path in excel Trusted Add-in catalog and checked show
  in menu. closed excel and open it back.
- I can see my addin under shared addin.
- I selected and add in Excel too.

[image]

Unfortunately I don't see `Contoso.ADD42()` function. I re-did it, still no luck.  Did I miss any step, did I do something wrong?

My updated manifest.xml as follows:

[image]

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue that you've described. I followed the instructions in the **Excel-Custom-Functions** README that you've linked to (steps 1-4 in the **To use the project** section) and when I type `=Contoso.ADD42(1,2)` in a cell and hit enter, the custom function executes and the text value `45` appears in the cell. What platform are you testing this on? And, just to verify -- are you beginning the formula with an equals sign (as described in step #4 of the instructions)?

Comment: I'm using office 2016 on windows 10 Pro. of course i am always starting formula in excel from "=" operator only.

Comment: I attached snip as well

Comment: Thanks for providing this additional information; I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You have to join the [Office Insider](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider) program to install the version of Excel that will work with custom functions. Use the "**Insider**" channel (As the [prerequisites](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions#prerequisites) section suggests).

You might also not be using a sufficiently recent build of Office. I'd suggest you verify that you meet the prerequisites that are described in the Excel Custom Functions sample [README](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions#prerequisites). Specifically, you must be using Office Build number **8711 or later** in order to use custom functions.

Comment: My current office version is 8201.2200. when i try to update it. i get message "office is already up to date". what can i do get Office Build number 8711 or later?

Comment: I've updated my answer to add a note about the Office Insider program.

Comment: I updated my office now current office Version is 1711(Build 8730.2046 Click-to-Run). still function is not getting appeared.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you're still having trouble. I've reached out to the product team for more info about this issue, and will update this thread with any new information received.

Comment: That build is new enough. I suspect some issue with the manifest xml or the code. Did you make any changes from the sample or is it copied exactly? Could you post your xml file so I can see?

Comment: I added mainfest.xml snip. let me know any more info do i need to add?

Comment: Could you refresh your IE browser cache and try again? We've just released an update to the JavaScript library at https://appsforoffice.edog.officeapps.live.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

Comment: I started everything fresh in new computer. still no luck.

Comment: There are 2 channels in the Insider program: "Insider" and "Monthly Channel (Targeted)". You can see your channel name on the File > Account page in Excel. You need to be on the "Insider" channel for custom functions to work. Which channel are you on?

Comment: It's Monthly Channel (Targeted).

Comment: @RaviAnand Did changing to Insider Channel solved your problem? Cause I'm facing the same issue, and even changed it to Insider Channel, but still cannot see the formulas.

Comment: @Zohaib it did not work that time when i was trying. i am not sure about now.

Comment: @RaviAnand Thanks for replying. It worked for me once I deleted the office cache